# Instantaneous Growth Equation

Tags: differential-equations

Find a formula for  y[x] if it is known that the instantaneous growth rate   y'[x] is proportional to y[x] and it is known that y[0]=5 and y[5.7]=10.
Does the value of  y[x] double every 5.7 years?

I need solve this using Mathematica software.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. If you have started learning Mathematica, then you will find that the introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Comment: y is an exponential function: c0 Exp[c2 x]. And yes it doubles every 5.7 years.